# get my posts count in discussion board

Tags: 2016, jsom

how can I get my posts count that I have posted in the discussion board using JSOM or REST API
and show the count in HTML div tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the posts count in REST API using data.d.results.length.
Then append the count to the div using jQuery as shown below:

```
var currentUserId;
function getItems(url) {  
currentUserId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        return $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            }
        });
    }

getItems( "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('<list title>')/Items?$select=Author/Id,*&$expand=Author&$filter=(Author/Id eq '+currentUserId+')").done(function(data){

    var numofItems = data.d.results.length;
     $("#<div id>").append("<b>" + numofItems + "</b>");
});
```

Comment: Karen is asking about count of his posts only. So URL should be specific to his user ID.

Comment: REST URL updated to filter items based on the author.

Comment: "_spPageContextInfo.userId" gets the current login user id that i have stored in variable "currentUserId"

Comment: it is working now but it always returns 0

Comment: please help @sohail

Comment: Just create a new post (item) with your user id and check the count with the same user id. If it still returns 0 then check if you have provided proper list name in the rest URL.

Comment: I am using the system account, return 0!

Comment: please any other solution to filter using username / current user